# Using substring with XQUERY

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a multiple nodes with a date of the style:
2019-11-16

I want to get the month of theses dates, so far I tried this and some variations on this:

```
let $DATE:=data(//activity/DATE)
let $month:=substring($DATE, 6, 2)
return $month
```

But I have an error saying that the cardinality doesn't match the expected parameter,I know its a string related issue, if I insert manually a date like '1999-12-24' it returns the expected value but I need it to read the dates and then return them as indicated in the substring, any ideas? I thought that data("...") returned a string but it seems like it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the path `//activity/DATE` selects more than one element, you will need to check that and if so, decide whether you want to select only the first with `(//activity/DATE)[1]` or `head(//activity/DATE)`, then you can certainly call `substring` on that one selected element, even without using the `data` function.

If you want to extract a sequence of month numbers from a sequence of `DATE` elements you can use `//activity/DATE/substring(., 6, 2)`.

Note however, that your format fits the `xs:date` data type so using `//activity/DATE/xs:date(.)` seems more appropriate to deal with dates and then you can exploit the functions on `xs:date`, `//activity/DATE/month-from-date(xs:date(.))`: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-month-from-date.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to iterate through a list of dates, your solution worked, much appreciated